# How can I manage multiple Scrum Backlogs with Agilo?

Tags: scrum, backlog

We have now installed Agilo to manage our Scrum projects, and we have that proble: we can handle just one backlog. How can we have different backlogs?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (Unfortunately, this question is too old to be  migrated.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some other tools you might like to try.

Installable onsite are Rally, Version One. I think Thoughtworks' Mingle is available onsite but they prefer to host it for you.

You may also like to try some of the new online Lean tools: LeanKitKanban, AgileZen.

If possible, get one or more big whiteboards and some post-its, then back it up / produce reports etc. electronically. Excel worked well for this for me. Also there's nothing like the tactile and immediate visual feedback from moving post-its around. You can use index cards and holders or blue-tack if the post-its fall off.

You can also represent the multiple backlogs at different scales; for instance, showing whole features, apps or systems completed at a project or programme level while tracking the smaller stories and tasks at a team level.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try other tools? :)

Comment: Thanks ;-) I think also it is a good idea. Using a tool that is a Frankenstein made up over a tool meant for another purpose, doesn't make me happy anymore :-(
Can you recommend any other tool?

Comment: In fact I can because I'm involved with one - http://www.bananascrum.com/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple products? There should only be one product backlog for each product - having more than one doesn't make much sense.
To break down a product backlog, it often makes sense to add extra columns to the backlog for different categories within that product. That would make it easier to filter and see different areas of the backlog quickly and efficiently.